# React Router Navlink to another Page using props passed from a Parent

Tags: javascript, reactjs, react-router, react-link

I am redering cards with unique "types" that link to different pages based on the props.type passed to it in react.

Am I correctly dynamically creating these router links?

```
import React from 'react';
import {render} from 'react-dom';
import {Route, NavLink, Switch, Redirect} from 'react-router-dom';
import Answered from '../../containers/Blog/answered/answered-posts';
import './Post.css';

import RothIRA from '../../containers/Types/RothIRA';

function post(props) {

  return (
    <article className="Post" onClick={props.clicked}>

      <NavLink to={{
        pathname: '/' + props.type,
        hash: '#submit',
        search: '?quick-submit=true'
      }}>
        {props.type}
      </NavLink>

      <Switch>
        <Route path={'/' + props.type} component={RothIRA}/>
      </Switch>
    </article>

  );

}

export default post;
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

First of all, It's meanless to use the `Switch` tag if there is just one `Route` in the tag. Because the `Switch` tag is rendering only one `Route` that matched first even there are two or more matched elements in the `Switch` tag.

this is the official document for the `Switch` tag https://reactrouter.com/web/api/Switch

The second one is the `RothIRA` component. It's rendered always no matter what type is routed. It's okay if you made the `RothIRA` component render contents flexibly according to the route. But if you don't, it will render the same thing every time is routed. If you did, look at these examples.

this example is rendering different component according to the route

```js
import React from 'react';
import {render} from 'react-dom';
import {Route, NavLink, Switch, Redirect} from 'react-router-dom';
import Answered from '../../containers/Blog/answered/answered-posts';
import './Post.css';

import RothIRA1 from '../../containers/Types/RothIRA1';
import RothIRA2 from '../../containers/Types/RothIRA2';

function post(props) {

  return (
    <article className="Post" onClick={props.clicked}>

      <NavLink to={{
        pathname: '/' + props.type,
        hash: '#submit',
        search: '?quick-submit=true'
      }}>
        {props.type}
      </NavLink>

      <Switch>
        <Route path={'/1'} component={RothIRA1}/>
        <Route path={'/2'} component={RothIRA2}/>
      </Switch>
    </article>

  );

}

export default post;
```

this example is rendering the `RothIRA` but let it know what type is with props

```js
import React from 'react';
import {render} from 'react-dom';
import {Route, NavLink, Switch, Redirect} from 'react-router-dom';
import Answered from '../../containers/Blog/answered/answered-posts';
import './Post.css';

import RothIRA from '../../containers/Types/RothIRA';

function post(props) {

  return (
    <article className="Post" onClick={props.clicked}>

      <NavLink to={{
        pathname: '/' + props.type,
        hash: '#submit',
        search: '?quick-submit=true'
      }}>
        {props.type}
      </NavLink>

      <Route path={'/' + props.type} render={() => (<RothIRA type={props.type} />)}/>
    </article>

  );

}

export default post;
```

And other things are looking good for me.

Comment: this is great thanks! I am going to try this out! I was wondering where to implement the render() function and this answered that for me as well.

Comment: If i have a parent container for this component "post" how would I insert it into the parent? Would if be <Post /> ? I get an unidentified route when I do this.

Comment: @MattLaszcz <Post type={'animal'} /> maybe work. But I'm not sure because I don't know what is unidentified. It can be Post component, props.type, or anything. I think I tell you what is the problem when I know specific error log

Comment: I actually figured it all out for now ! Thanks again for the help.